# When trying to rebase why is the proposed commit history wildly out of order?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Here is my commit history:

```
0fb5310 me     Mon Jan 6 08:33:57 2014 -0500   four
f407eac me     Mon Jan 6 08:32:34 2014 -0500   three
c8ede60 me     Mon Jan 6 08:31:49 2014 -0500   two
06dd7e9 me     Mon Jan 6 08:30:04 2014 -0500   one
026cb0d me     Mon Jan 6 04:21:57 2014 -0800   Initial commit
```

I want to squash the entire commit history except for the most recent commit.  When I try to do this I get the following error.

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~4
```

Why can I not rebase up to the first commit?

When I do

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Why is the interactive proposed history wildly out of order `HEAD~2`->`HEAD~4`->`HEAD~0`?

Why does it not show all 4 commits (`HEAD~0`, `HEAD~1`, `HEAD~2`, `HEAD~3`) ?

```
pick c8ede60 two
pick 026cb0d Initial commit
pick 0fb5310 four
```

Also why does `$ git rev-parse HEAD~4` result an in error `fatal: ambiguous argument`HEAD~4`: unknown revision or path not in the working tree` while the interactive prompt for the rebase shows `HEAD~4` as the Initial commit?

**Here is my graph history**
`$ git log --oneline --graph`

```
* 0fb5310 four
*   f407eac three
|\
| * 026cb0d Initial commit
* c8ede60 two
* 06dd7e9 one
```

Comment: Are there merges in your history? What's the output of `git log --oneline --graph`?

Comment: There are merges in my history, I have updated my question with the output of `git log --oneline --graph`

Answer (score 1):

Rebase tries to treat history linearly, but merges are not a linear history. As such, if you have merges in your history rebase is not going to show things in the same order that you necessarily committed them.

Furthermore, the `~` operator only goes up the "first parent" path, which means that `HEAD~3` is as far as you can go because it's not going down the side branch. `HEAD~4` doesn't mean "my fourth commit chronologically before `HEAD`", it means "the fourth commit before `HEAD` going up the first-parent side of the history" - in this case, only the `*` in the first column of the graph log.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amber points out, your branch history is not linear

```
* 0fb5310 four               HEAD
*   f407eac three            HEAD~1
|\
| * 026cb0d Initial commit   HEAD~1^2  second parent of HEAD~1
* c8ede60 two                HEAD~2
* 06dd7e9 one                HEAD~3
```

You can use `git rebase -p` to preserve merges, but apparently (according to the man page for `git-rebase`) you shouldn't use `-p` and `-i` together (which is unfortunate, since that is often useful).